# How can I show text touching div borders?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a DIV containing some text.
The div is positioned absolutely. It has `style="border:1px solid black"` so it shows as a nice rectangle.
Now within this rectangle I want to show text which either a top or bottom (whichever is easier) border touching the text, like in the folowing picture:

[image]

I have the following requirements:

1. I don't want to underline the text- this is not the issue
2. I don't want to manually position the text within the DIV

The expected behavior would be: I set the position of the DIV and the text automatically touches the border (top or bottom border)- no matter what font-family or font-size I set.

The reason I need this is to be able to position elements on screen in HTML in exact positions- like on a PDF.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. Browsers don't have that level of sophistication with the fonts they use.

Comment: @Juhana That's what I am afraid of. I could even JavaScript if it helped...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can with pure CSS if the font-size is a fixed value, by using an extra `span`:

HTML:

```
<div id="box"><span>FAKTURA</span></div>
```

CSS:

```
#box {
    height: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
}
#box span {
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

[Check JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S8rPZ/)

However, your point 3 says that the font-size can be different. Than you can't fix it with pure CSS. However with JQuery you can:

HTML stays the same.

CSS:

```
#box {
    overflow: hidden;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
}
#box span {
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    var fontSize = parseInt( $("#box span").css('font-size'), 10);
    fontSize = fontSize - 4;
    $("#box").height( fontSize+"px" );
});
```

Also check [the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S8rPZ/1/).
The JQuery needs some adjustment. For example when you change the font-size to 90px, the border doesn't touch the text. And changing it to 12px, the text disappears. That needs some adjusting.

Comment: Nice one. Thanks! I think height = 0.9*font-size does the trick in most cases!